# Set same sized buttons on the form

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I am using Java Swing and I designed a form page with a few buttons like play, pause, stop & break.  They have different sizes, so they seem bad. I want to set size of the buttons to the same size.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setSize(Dimension d)` where you specify the size of each button.

Or you can use different layouts to your application - I am mostly using the GridLayout which works really fine for me - see the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in the comments: Better approach is to use some layout managers to handle the size for you. If you set size of button explicitly via command above, it can cause looking it "not nice" if you resize the window. Layout can do this for you more nicely.

BTW, if you will use

```
private JFrame application;
application.pack();
```

prior showing the application to the user, it can "miracelously" cure all "not nice" looking buttons and handles

Comment: +1 for `GridLayout` -1  (bordering -2) for `setSize()`.  Net result - 0.

Comment: Trying defend myself, that I was answering the question is not good approach, right? Actually, I tried to solve the same problem by setting sizes, but then found out that the layout is better approach. Will probably edit the answer a bit ")

Comment: The edits are a good start, but not yet enough.  Calling `setSize()` is bad because 1) If the layout will honor *any* size, it is the preferred size, rather than the size. 2) Coming up with the right minimum dimensions (or size, or preferred size) for a button across multiple font sizes and faces, on different OS, using different PLAFS (etc.) is not an easy task.  Each component goes to considerable effort to calculate that size, it is unwise to try & guess it.

Comment: +1, I liked the info, but as stated before, `setSize(...)` is really not the way to go :-)